# Limit Power BI slicer to two (2) options

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a column called "teams" and I want to write a dax statement that will limit user to only two teams at a time. Please remember that Teams is going to be a slicer.

```
   Valid Selection = 
   VAR SelectedTeams = COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED('query1'[teams]))
   RETURN
   IF(
   SelectedTeams <= 2, 
   1, 
   "You are limited to a maximum of two teams in the slicer."
   )
```

The above dax statement is not working. I am looking to limit slicer options to two teams maximum. Any ideas?

Comment: You can show/hide visuals based on a measure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66909502/show-hide-a-visual-on-power-bi-based-on-a-measure